# WCF - Is it better to use IList / IDictionary instead of an Array?

Tags: arrays, performance, wcf

What gives more performance?

Use normal arrays like string[]

Or is it better to use IList or IDictionary instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think the performance is identical - in the end, when the message is serialized into XML and sent across the wire, the XSD's capability of representing a *list of elements* is used, no matter which approach you use in your C# code.